# Everything keeps moving to the bottom

Tags: html, css, position

Is there any way that I could position everything such that the items (such as text/pictures) can overlay?

For example:

```
<body>

    <header>
        <div class="navbar">
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="class1">image</div>
    <div class="class2">text</div>
    <div class="class3">text</div>

</body>
```

I want the class 2 text and class 3 to be displayed over the image. However, in this format, they just appear below the image.

I tried putting the class 2 and class 3 inside of class 1

```
<body>

    <header>
        <div class="navbar">
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="class1">image
        <div class="class2">text</div>
        <div class="class3">text</div>
    </div>

</body>
```

However, I found this very troublesome. Everytime I add a new thing into class 1, the whole page will move.

Even though `position: relative; and position: absolute;` solves this it won't work if I try to display an element over the whole page itself (outside of class 1 - goes to the bottom of the page). I am trying to have something like this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_alert.asp appear over my whole page.

Tried setting the  with `position: relative;` and the alert message box as 'position: absolute;`  but this didn't do anything. Could someone please give some suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure what you wanna achieve ? did you try wrapping your text in a `div` and give it a position with `z-index`

Comment: I want to display it over the navbar (generally overlap the whole page) putting the class 2 and class 3 in class 1 only allows them to be displayed on the image itself

Comment: is your navbar on fixed position ?

Comment: no i only have a `position: relative;` for my navbar <header> I tried setting it to fixed but the whole navbar disappeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand what you need but maybe your need is something like that :

```css
.class1 {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("https://images.sftcdn.net/images/t_app-cover-l,f_auto/p/ce2ece60-9b32-11e6-95ab-00163ed833e7/260663710/the-test-fun-for-friends-screenshot.jpg");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>

    <header>
        <div class="navbar">
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="class1">
        <div class="class2">text2</div>
        <div class="class3">text3</div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: what if i want to display it over the navbar? (generally overlap the whole page) this only works for texts that i want to place inside the image

Answer (score 0):

Yeah , like this.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="class1">image</div> //use an img tag here
    <div class="text-container"> 
     <div class="class2">text</div>
     <div class="class3">text</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.text-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set you content at bottom of the page the try the solution, it is for bottom right poistion

```css
.class1{
      position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
 <header>
        <div class="navbar">
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="class1">image
        <div class="class2">text</div>
        <div class="class3">text</div>
    </div>
```